# Counting number of holes in a number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of "holes" in a number. That is, where 8 has two holes and 0, 4, 6, 9 have one hole and the rest have none.

For some reason I'm getting a return of undefined and I'm pulling my hair out over it. Am I missing something?

```
var numOfHoles = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {

   if (num === 8) {
       numOfHoles += 2; 
      }
       else if (num === 0 || num === 4 || num === 6 || num === 9) {
           numOfHoles++;
    }
     else
        numOfHoles;
  }
    console.log(numOfHoles);
}
```

Comment: I see an extra `}`...

Comment: Is `num` a string (suggested by having a `.length`  property) or a number (as suggested by comparing it strictly with numbers)? It can't be both.

Comment: What is `else numOfHoles;` supposed to do?

Comment: Why not just use a switch? there are only so many numbers to deal with (10, I've been told)

Comment: you have a mix of 1-line statements which do not require brackets at all, plus bracketed code.  Line them up.

Comment: Surely just delete `else numOfHoles;`? It seems to do nothing...

Comment: can there be more than digit in the number..?

Comment: replace num in for loop block with num[i]

Comment: I see no `return` statement here, and you say you're getting a return value of `undefined`. Please provide a working example.

Answer (score 2):

Simply take the number, split it into an array of ints, and then use an arrow function as the argument for reduce to total the correlating value from the number to holes map.

```js
function numHoles(n){
       return (""+n).split('').reduce((t,i) => t+=+"1000101021"[i],0);
}
document.write(numHoles(48488621597));
```

Comment: Since you're using ES6, a block would have sufficed instead of that IIFE… Otherwise I'd recommend to `return` the closure from the IIFE instead of that outer-scope assignment.

Comment: In case you want to golf, `let nums = [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,2,1];` :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Agreed ;)

Comment: …or actually, there's no need to cache a string (it's internalised anyway), so just make it `"1000101021"[n]` and do away with the IIFE :-D

Comment: @Bergi - Totally, now that it is just a literal that makes sense. Much golfier :P

Answer (score 1):

Unless there was some code missing from the top when you copied this over, it looks like you need to either remove the trailing bracket or declare this as a function (see below).

Edit: This is a strange question. Firstly, the answers referencing using an index on num might not work as expected. The easiest, but possibly not best, answer would be to convert the number to a string, then index and compare to characters instead of numbers.

As everyone else has mentioned, it makes things much easier if you maintain proper code format :)

```
function countNumHoles(num) {
        var numOfHoles = 0;

        var numStr = num.toString();

        for (i = 0; i < num.toString().length; i++) {
            if (numStr[i] === '8') {
                numOfHoles += 2;
            } else if (numStr[i] === '0' || numStr[i] === '4' || numStr[i] === '6' || numStr[i] === '9') {
                numOfHoles++;
            }
        }

        console.log(numOfHoles);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this :

```
var num = [9,4,5];
var numOfHoles = 0;

for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
    if (num[i] == 8)
    {
        numOfHoles += 2; 
    }
    else if (num[i]== 0 || num[i]== 4 || num[i]== 6 || num[i]== 9)
    {
        numOfHoles++;
    }
}
console.log(numOfHoles);
```

You had multiple little error.
First of all you didn't need `else { numOfHoles }` which dont mean anything.
And you need if you try to check every elements to use the indexation of the element so you need to use `num[i]`.

Comment: It's still coming back as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you idented wrongly the code, so it's harder to see the errors. The correct identation of your code goes like this:

```
var numOfHoles = 0;

for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {

    if (num === 8) {
       numOfHoles += 2; 
    } else if (num === 0 || num === 4 || num === 6 || num === 9) {
        numOfHoles++;
    } else
        numOfHoles;

    console.log(numOfHoles);
}
```

So now with the correct identation you can easily see that `else numOfHoles;` isn't needed, num ins't defined and length is for string or arrays. Also console.log is better outside the loop in order to run only once. Here is a functional version:

```
var numOfHoles = 0;
limit = 5;

for (num = 0; num <= limit; num++) {

    if (num === 8) {
       numOfHoles += 2; 
    } else if (num === 0 || num === 4 || num === 6 || num === 9) 
        numOfHoles++;
}

console.log(numOfHoles);
```

Comment: It's not needed, yes, but it's not wrong. And your updated code still doesn't work.

Comment: my ideia was to correct only some things in order for the user to discover the rest. But with a bit of pressure we promptly correct the code ;)

Comment: And now it got worse :-/

Comment: Well, it does something, but for sure not what was asked for by the OP.

Comment: well.. it corrects the problem he has having... I think it's valid... if he doesn't like it, accept another one... :/ But I still didn't understand why it's worse than the previous version....

Answer (score 0):

Considering all the answers on top, you have some mistakes with braces. But you are counting num of holes in array, but you don't have indexes. Here is my test snippet. And it has nothing to do with empty numOfHoles. But i still recommend to remove it.

```
var numOfHoles = 0;
var num = [4,0,9,8,5,5,5];
for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {

if (num[i] === 8) {
    numOfHoles += 2;
}
else if (num[i] === 0 || num[i] === 4 || num[i] === 6 || num[i] === 9) {
    numOfHoles++;
}
else
    numOfHoles;
}
console.log(numOfHoles);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to answer. You used the length property in the variable "num". But strictly used the comparison. The rule if always be false, considering that (string "8" !== 8). This type of comparison requires that the variables have the same type.In this case or you use an integer or an Array and uses the variable i to access your elements in the loop for

Solution, or you comes in as a string and uses the following system [if (num === "8")], or working on becoming a int, or work with an array (recommended). To know the best solution we needed to see more of the code.

Your code should stay that way. Of course, if you need something more specific, let us know

```
var num = [0,2,8,5];
var numOfHoles = 0;

for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
    if (num[i] == 8)
    {
        numOfHoles += 2;
    }
    else if (num[i]== 0 || num[i]== 4 || num[i]== 6 || num[i]== 9)
    {
        numOfHoles++;
    }
}
console.log(numOfHoles);
```